# How to do networking in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, networking

Hey i am new to developing apps using unity.

Needed help with how API calls are made in unity. How Network managers can be made to api calls? How objects can be created by mapping JSON? Is there a library that is used for doing networking generally? Can i get some sample implementation to look at?

is this used for networking generally?
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Networking.UnityWebRequest.html?_ga=2.260182286.2011413046.1587971291-955861227.1582882092

Any leads would be of great help! Thanks.

Comment: What exactly does `networking` mean to you and in your use-case?

Comment: Hey @derHugo ! I was planning to make an application where i would have to get some data from backend ... For an instance i have to call different apis to fetch a list of products,  product details. How can i create a manager to make API calls in unity.

Answer (score 0):

It's so simple!

1. Send a Request with `UnityWebRequest` (with [Post](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Networking.UnityWebRequest.Post.html) or [Get](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Networking.UnityWebRequest.Get.html) method)
2. Read the Response value
3. Make a `Struct` or `Class` with fields that you have in your response
4. Parse your response to your `Json Serialization` ([Read Here](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/JSONSerialization.html))

For example:

```
using System;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Networking;
using System.Collections;

// UnityWebRequest.Get example

// Access a website and use UnityWebRequest.Get to download a page.
// Also try to download a non-existing page. Display the error.

public class Example : MonoBehaviour
{
    [Serializable]
    public class MyClass
    {
        public int level;
        public float timeElapsed;
        public string playerName;
    }

    void Start()
    {
        // A correct website page.
        StartCoroutine(GetRequest("https://www.example.com"));

        // A non-existing page.
        StartCoroutine(GetRequest("https://error.html"));
    }

    IEnumerator GetRequest(string uri)
    {
        using (UnityWebRequest webRequest = UnityWebRequest.Get(uri))
        {
            // Request and wait for the desired page.
            yield return webRequest.SendWebRequest();

            string[] pages = uri.Split('/');
            int page = pages.Length - 1;

            if (webRequest.isNetworkError)
            {
                Debug.Log(pages[page] + ": Error: " + webRequest.error);
            }
            else
            {
                var json = webRequest.downloadHandler.text;
                Debug.Log(pages[page] + ":\nReceived: " + json);

                var myObject = JsonUtility.FromJson<MyClass>(json); //<-- This is your result object
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Could you also help me with a manager or a service which i can create to make different API calls. Wouldn't this setup be redundant if i have to make multiple api calls?

Comment: Yea it's so simple, As you can see above, there is a parameter in `GetRequest` called `uri`. you can call this function by any URL that you want. for JSON parser, I can suggest make another string parameter like `parserClass`, and send class name to function. (Read here: https://answers.unity.com/questions/42498/how-do-i-convert-a-string-into-a-class-reference-i.html)(